# JavaScript polluting global namespace?

Tags: javascript, modular

Am I polluting the global namespace by setting up my JavaScript files like on the below? I am using webpack to compile the JS files into bundle.js

```
[javascript folder]
 - index.js
   [components]
     - navigation.js
     - carousel.js
```

**index.js**

```
import './components/navigation';
import './components/carousel';
```

**navigation.js**

```
const Navigation = () => {
   const button = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
   const header = document.querySelector('.header');

   button.onclick = () => {
      header.classList.toggle('active');
   }
}

Navigation();
```

**carousel.js**

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';

var swiper = new Swiper('.js-slider', {
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination'
    },
});
```

Comment: No, the variables you define in your modules `navigation.js` and `carousel.js` are defined only in the scope of these modules

Comment: If `navigation.js` and `carousel.js` are treated correctly as modules, then you won't pollute the global namespace, because `const Navigation` and `var swiper` would be defined within the scope of the module.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot for the explanation